# Get a file list from TFS

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of files from a specific folder ("$/theproject/trunk/setup/") in TFS without putting them in the local folder.

So far I've managed to connect, create a workspace and a working folder:

```
        var server = RegisteredTfsConnections.GetProjectCollection(new Uri("http://hostname:8080/"));
        var projects = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(server);
        var versionControl = (VersionControlServer)projects.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

        var workspace = versionControl.CreateWorkspace(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName + "-installer", versionControl.AuthorizedUser);
        try
        {
            WorkingFolder folder = new WorkingFolder("$/theproject/trunk/setup/", "C:\\aTempFolder");
            workspace.CreateMapping(folder);

            //this would get all files to the local folder, right?
            //what should I do instead to just get a file list?
            workspace.Get(); 

        }
        finally
        {
            workspace.Delete();
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's done like this:

```
        var server = RegisteredTfsConnections.GetProjectCollection(new Uri("http://hostname:8080/"));
        var projects = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(server);
        var versionControl = (VersionControlServer)projects.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

        var newestDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        Item newestItem = null;
        var items = versionControl.GetItems("$/theproject/trunk/setup/*.msi");
        foreach (var item in items.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType != ItemType.File)
                continue;

            if (item.CheckinDate > newestDate)
            {
                newestItem = item;
                newestDate = item.CheckinDate;
            }
        }
        newestItem.DownloadFile("C:\\temp\\" + Path.GetFileName(newestItem.ServerItem));
```

Comment: References: "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client" and "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client"

Comment: Needs to add RecursionType.Full as parameter to the method GetItems, otherwise it doesn't bring items from subfolder.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
ItemSet items = versionControl.GetItems(folder.ServerItem, RecursionType.Full);
```

Comment: I would have accepted your answer if you had added it before mine (or if it had been more detailed). Now you got only +1.